# How to represent a column list (pandas) in a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

When I save a data frame with a column whose values are lists, the CSV file ignores this and represents it without a comma between items.

Before I save my data frame the value looks like this:

[image]

Then I save the CSV file and when I try to load my CSV file the value looks like this:

[image]

And I want it as a list.

I would like for help please

Answer (score 0):

Event tho informations provided are too few to give you correct answer, but i hope this snipper may help you figure out a solution.

```py
import csv  

header = ['name', 'area', 'country_code2', 'country_code3']
data = ['Afghanistan', 652090, 'AF', 'AFG']


   with open('countries.csv', 'w', 
   encoding='UTF8') as f:
       writer = csv.writer(f)

       # write the header
       writer.writerow(header)

       # write the data
       writer.writerow(data)
```

With that you get a csv like :

```
name,area,country_code2,coundtry_code3
Afghanistan,652090,AF,AFG
```